# Azure Database for PostgreSQL server: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, dbeaver, pg-hba.conf

In my Azure portal I created the resource "Azure Database for PostgreSQL server". I set up the firewall to enable two Virtual Networks (in order to allow the correct functioning of two applications) and the IP address of my local computer (in order to be able to work on the database using DBeaver as client). This has worked for several months although, since I have a dynamic IP address, I often have to change the enabled address. Now I'm trying to update it but, when I try to connect to the database via DBeaver, I get the following error:

`FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XX.XX.XX", user "myuser", database "mydatabase", SSL on`

where "XX.XX.XX.XX" is exactly the IP address I have enabled in Azure.

I tried to install a second Client (pgAdmin) but I get the same error. Also, since my applications that use the database seem to work properly, I tried to verify the connection data that I use in DBeaver (host, database, user, password) but they are all correct.

In Azure, in the "Connection security" tab of my database (see image below) I read the following warning:

`Some network environments may not report the actual public-facing IP address needed to access your server.  Contact your network administrator if adding your IP address does not allow access to your server.`

So changing the IP address has no effect? How can I solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by restarting the database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-restart-server-portal

Comment: I restarted my server but the issue still persists.Any other pointers??

Comment: If restarting doesn't help and if the message contains `SSL off` it means that the client is not using tls which is required by Azure Postgresql. Try to enable it.

Answer (score 9):

make ssl connection non mandatory in server parameters for postgres service in azure, its dynamic parameter so no postgres service restart not required

or fix/configure application to use secure(ssl) connections only

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> In the Azure Portal change **require_secure_transport** from server parameters to **OFF**.

Comment: can you please provide link to that original article where you have quoted it from?